# Memoryerror in python for loop

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have a column for duration where time is defined in "min", "sec" and "season" for movies.i am trying to bring all value of duration in minutes.
below funtion seems to be working but getting memoryerror.please help.

```py
    import pandas as pd

    Netflix_df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\mrauthan\OneDrive - ascenaretail.com\Desktop\Ascena\DS\PythonPractice\Netflix\netflix_titles.csv")

    Netflix_split=Netflix_df['duration'].str.split(" ",0,expand=True)
    print(Netflix_split[0])

    for x in Netflix_split[1]:
    #if Netflix_split[1]=='hours':
    if x  in 'hours':
        Netflix_split[0]=Netflix_split[0]*60
    elif x in 'Seasons':
        Netflix_split[0]=Netflix_split[0]*60*24
    else:
        Netflix_split[0]=Netflix_split[0]*60*24*24
```

Output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/mrauthan/OneDrive - ascenaretail.com/Desktop/Ascena/DS/Python Practice/Netflix/Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/mrauthan/OneDrive - ascenaretail.com/Desktop/Ascena/DS/Python Practice/Netflix')
0       90
1       94
2        1
3        1
4       99
        ..
6229    13
6230     4
6231    60
6232     2
6233    10
Name: 0, Length: 6234, dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-860d9eb41224>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/mrauthan/OneDrive - ascenaretail.com/Desktop/Ascena/DS/Python Practice/Netflix/Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/mrauthan/OneDrive - ascenaretail.com/Desktop/Ascena/DS/Python Practice/Netflix')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/mrauthan/OneDrive - ascenaretail.com/Desktop/Ascena/DS/Python Practice/Netflix/Test.py", line 17, in <module>
    Netflix_split[0]=Netflix_split[0]*60*24*24

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 1048, in wrapper
    result = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 968, in na_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 221, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 127, in _evaluate_numexpr
    result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)

MemoryError
```

Comment: I see you are already doing `print(Netflix_split[0])`, which was going to be my suggestion.  Is the value there what you expect?

Comment: Yes... actually value of columns are like 2 mins, 2 hours, 2 season.Netflix_split[0] show value as numeric and Netflix_split[1] show value as mins,hours,season...so i am trying to bring it to one parameter like mins with some calculation for further analysis....

Comment: `for x in Netflix_split[1]:` looks suspicious.  You shouldn't need to repeat the following calculations more than once since they are vectorized.  Try running your code through a debugger or adding a `print(Netflix_split[0])` inside of that loop, and I think you will see that the numbers get much larger than they should.

Comment: Thanks this issue is resolved after removing for loop..i am new to python so able to get issue happened because of for loop and vectorized..
Can you help how i can fetch each row and update it using if condition...
i am getting this error after removing loop...it is fetching all row to if condition it seems

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series

Comment: Thanks everyone i was able to move forward and made it work.

Comment: Thanks 0x5453 for help..Appreciate on this one.